# Convert to time to millisecond

Tags: android, time, calendar

I want to checked if set time is less than calender(mobile device)time.
 It shows alarms set and if set time is not more that 1.5 hr it shows "ruko ruko" message. If both conditions are false then it will go to else condition.
 It does not gave me expected results. Here is my code:

```
 GregorianCalendar mcalender=new GregorianCalendar();
mcalender.set(2013, 7, 17, 13, 0);

if(mcalender.getTimeInMillis()<=cal.getTimeInMillis()){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sets ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if(mcalender.getTimeInMillis()+5400000<=cal.getTimeInMillis()){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "ruko ruko", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Time not gone ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that mcalender.getTimeInMillis() is checked first. For example, when you alarm is set for 5:30, at 4:30 the first part will be true already, so the else if section is entirely skipped. Just got to reverse the order and that will do :)

```
    if(mcalender.getTimeInMillis()+5400000<=cal.getTimeInMillis()){
        //If still have more than 1.5 hours to go (i.e. 2 hours left etc)
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "ruko ruko", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(mcalender.getTimeInMillis()<=cal.getTimeInMillis()){
        //Not more than 1.5 hours, but still not time up yet.
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sets ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        //Time is up. Run action.
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Time not gone ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: @sijie-i'm just using this code for setting for alarm and my prblm is that if set alarm for 1.5 hrs and alarm time is 1.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't really get your problem here - you set an alarm for 1.5 hours but the app says that you only set for 1 hour?
If so, then this part of the code isn't the problem, it seems.

Comment: @sijie-actully my prblm is that if i set alarm 4.00 pm and its finish time is 5.30 means 1.5 hrs .if i want checked before 4 clock it show is me alarm is set and if i want checked between 4 to 5.30 it show me time not finish...and otherwise if time is finished show and run else condition pls help me

Comment: edited. it's due to the problem that 
`if(mcalender.getTimeInMillis()<=cal.getTimeInMillis()){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sets ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}`
is also true if time is within 1.5 hours, but that's not what you want to have.

Comment: @sijie123-actullay i have used two Serviced Class for this when time is matching the first alarm call the first service class and on destroy first service class one alarm again set that is call after 1.5 hrs later after calling first alarm that's why i m checking which alarm is left